# Translate Text in Firestore extension duplicating translations?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, translate, firebase-extensions

My Firestore database has a collection of "products" for which I had to create two subcollections that are very similar named "attributes" and "default_attributes". They contain dictionaries within the dictionaries and the translate text extension it is my understanding that does not work that way. Both subcollections are very similar, in fact, the default_attribute would not exist without the attributes.

I'm having the extension translate the name in one subcollection and in the other subcollection, I'm translating the name AND options but they are in a field called "attribute_info". i.e.

```
{
  attribute_info: {
    name: "Color",
    option: "black"
  }
}
```

In the collection path fields of the extension configuration, I have the paths defined as {products}/{document}/{attributes} and {products}/{document}/{default_attributes}.

**The issue I'm running into is** that the extension is translating the field "name" in both subcollections. I finally solved this by renaming the field "attribute_name" from the previous "name". If anyone has come across this issue I would like to know how they solved it. I would prefer to keep the names as I originally had them in my database.